# MS CRM 2011 Creating quote with REST to user with read-only access

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm creating Quotes in own calculation system and exporting them to MS CRM 2011 throught REST API with credentials of users. Then those quotes are displayed in CRM as theirs (as if they created it by clicking in CRM). But now we want to edit privilege, so users can these quote only read. But this mean, that throught REST API I'm unable to create quote with their credentials.
Is there a way how to create new Quote as user, which has read-only access throught web?
Or is it possible to change authorship after quote was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the record's owner inside CRM 2011 there are 3 ways:

- Use impersonation, as described in this article: [TechNet - Impersonate Another User](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334744.aspx)
- Set the `ownerid` field when you create the record (C# example)

```cs
Entity quote = new Entity("quote");
// set the fields
// ...
// set the owner
Guid ownerId = new Guid("BFC777ED-5E79-E111-8489-00166D63156F");
quote["ownerid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", ownerId);
service.Create(quote);
```

- execute the `AssignRequest` message to update the record's owner, as explained in this article: [MSDN - AssignRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.assignrequest.aspx)

In your case when you create the quote using the REST API you need to set the `ownerid` field with the GUID of the selected user.

Is not possible to change the owner of an existing record using REST.

Comment: Impersonation is not supported in for the REST API in Dynamics CRM 2011.

Comment: You are right, I modified my answer to make it clearer. Thanks.